# Directed Infinity vs Indeterminant in this output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, version-12.1

When I evaluate

```
Limit[( E^((  I (-(1/2) m (xa^2 + xb^2) \[Omega] Cot[(ta - tb) \[Omega]] +      m xa xb \[Omega] Csc[(ta - tb) \[Omega]]))/\[HBar]) \[Omega]^  n)/Sqrt[Sin[(-ta + tb) \[Omega]]], \[Omega] -> 0]
```

In mathematica 12.1, it gives me the result unevaluated.

But if I do the same operation in mathematica 5, it gives me

```
E^(DirectedInfinity[-Sign[(-1 + 2 n) (ta - tb) \[HBar]]]/((ta - tb) \[HBar]))
```

Is there a way I can force the recent version of mathematica to give me this result?